# Bot replying to app_mention event in the wrong channel

Tags: php, slack, slack-api

I'm trying to work with the slack Event Subscription `app_mention`, but I'm having some issues.

My backend is PHP, and I'm using [this class](https://github.com/maknz/slack).

Basically, what's happening is, if I have my bot user in multiple channels and someone mentions the bot, it will only reply in a single channel.

For example;

I have the bot user in 2 channels

- bot-testing
- development

If I @ mention the bot in the `development` channel, it will send it's reply in the `bot-testing` channel.

My code used to send the message:

```
$client->to('#' . $event['channel'])->send("Hi. I'm currently under development.");
```

and my `$event` variable looks like this:

```
{"type":"app_mention","text":"<@UFT4EG0Q7> test","user":"UAKTRFH41","ts":"1548783398.055200","channel":"GAMED4PK5","event_ts":"1548783398.055200"}
```

but decoded obviously.

Why is my bot not replying in the correct channel?

Comment: Can you show me the code where `$client` is instantiated?

Comment: @ColmDoyle It's the same as documentation on the class, `$client = new \Maknz\Slack\Client(HOOK_URL);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So based on my reading of the PHP client you're using, that's designed for use with [Incoming Webhooks](https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks).

Incoming Webhooks have a 1:1 relationship with a conversation/channel, so you can't define the destination for your message in the payload you send to the API.

If you want to do that, you could try using one of the other [PHP SDKs](https://api.slack.com/community#php) built by the community.